# OpenOffice Daemon Problem

Tags: linux, daemon, openoffice.org

I'm using OpenOffice as a daemon. Sometimes, when the daemon is running a long time, CPU use spikes very high and then openoffice crash. At this point, the open office applicattion don't work and the documents don't be generated.

How can I restart automatically the openoffice daemon when this problem happens? Is there any way to monitor the service or to program a watchdog to handle it?

Thanks in advance, regards.

Comment: I think you have a better chance at getting a good answer at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), StackOverflow is for programming related questions (which yours is not about).

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use your distribution's services mechanism; Ubuntu and Fedora, for example, use [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html). Writing an upstart configuration file for your service probably wouldn't be too difficult.

If your distribution doesn't use upstart, you could either run it directly out of your `/etc/inittab` or use [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) to monitor your service. (The [linux-ha](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page) project also has some service monitoring tools, but may have more setup-requirements than you're interested in.)